# Can't catch a global hotkey (not a window-based app)

Tags: java, linux, awt, hotkeys

I'm trying to catch some keyboard event globally without using any window like `JFrame`, it should either a console app or a service (demon). Here is code I have:

```
class Main extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        AWTEventListener listener = new AWTEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
                try {
                    if (event instanceof KeyEvent) {
                        KeyEvent evt = (KeyEvent) event;
                        if (evt.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED &&
                                evt.getModifiers() == KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK &&
                                evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F) {
                            System.out.println("Ctrl+F is pressed!");
                        }
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(listener, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
        System.out.println("Listening to hotkeys...");
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main b = new Main();
        b.start();
    }
}
```

However, when I start it, it does nothing but printing "Listening to hotkeys..." when I press `Ctrl+F`. Even when I make a focus to other application or desktop, the result is still the same.

How did I do wrong?

Comment: I assume you mean you're trying to listen to OS global key strokes?  This can't be done from within Java without resorting to JNI/JNA solutions...

Comment: @MadProgrammer, doesn't AWT do that for me?

Comment: No, AWT filters the events so that it only deals with events that need to be processed by some component

Comment: @MadProgrammer, what do you mean? I can get and set clipboard by AWT, for example.

Comment: That's a different system.  AWT filters key board and mouse events based on the visibility of components it is managing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

class Main extends Thread 
{
    public void run() {

```
    AWTEventListener listener = new AWTEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
            try {
                if (event instanceof KeyEvent) {
                    KeyEvent evt = (KeyEvent) event;
                    if (evt.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED &&
                            evt.getModifiers() == KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK &&
                            evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F) {
                        System.out.println("Ctrl+F is pressed!");
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(listener, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK|AWTEvent.ACTION_EVENT_MASK);


}


public static void main(String[] args) {
new JFrame("").setVisible(true);
    Main b = new Main();
    b.start();
}
```

}

This is working. You can not use while loop like you have used in your program..

Comment: Ok sorry for this. then have to use JNI/JNA library you can check implementation of this library on http://grepcode.com/project/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.github.tulskiy/jkeymaster/

Comment: but it also uses a window.